# Send string from VB6 Winsock to WebSockets

Tags: websocket, vb6, winsock

I'm Making a VB6 application that connected to WebSocket , the Handshaking and reserving data part is working as i need and , currently i'm stucked at the Sending a string back to Websocket via Winsock,

i'm referring this blog post to work with websocket handshaking and things [VB6 + Winsock prepared websocket server](http://www.cnblogs.com/xiii/p/5165303.html)

I have tried like this

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory _
            Lib "kernel32" _
            Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, _
                                   Source As Any, _
                                   ByVal Length As Long)
______________________________________________________________________
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Winsock1.LocalPort = 6701
    Winsock1.Listen
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCommand1_Click()
    Dim str  As String
    Dim BT() As Byte

    str = StrConv(tbMsg.Text, vbUnicode)

    If WinSock1.State = sckConnected Then
       ReDim BT(Len(str) - 1)
       CopyMemory BT(0), str, Len(str)
       WinSock1.SendData StrConv(BT, vbUnicode)
    End If
End Sub
```

Form that method , i'm getting an error in browser like

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6701/' failed: A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client.

And also I have tried,

```
WinSock1.SendData StrToByte(tbMsg.Text, vbUnicode)


Public Function StrToByte(strInput As String) As Byte()
    Dim lPntr    As Long
    Dim bTmp()   As Byte
    Dim bArray() As Byte

    If Len(strInput) = 0 Then Exit Function
        ReDim bTmp(LenB(strInput) - 1) 'Memory length
        ReDim bArray(Len(strInput) - 1) 'String length
        CopyMemory bTmp(0), ByVal StrPtr(strInput), LenB(strInput)

        For lPntr = 0 To UBound(bArray)

            If bTmp(lPntr * 2 + 1) > 0 Then
                bArray(lPntr) = Asc(Mid$(strInput, lPntr + 1, 1))
            Else
                bArray(lPntr) = bTmp(lPntr * 2)
            End If
       Next lPntr

       StrToByte = bArray
End Function
```

From this method i'm getting an error from browser like

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6701/' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 1, reserved2 = 0, reserved3 = 1

And also I have tried,

```
Private Sub cmdCommand1_Click()
    Dim abData() As Byte
    Dim i        As Long
    Str = tbMsg.Text
    ' Convert string to bytes
    abData = StrConv(Str, vbFromUnicode)

    For i = 0 To UBound(abData)
        Debug.Print Hex(abData(i)); "='" & Chr(abData(i)) & "'"
    Next

    If VoicePrintSocket.State = 7 Then VoicePrintSocket.SendData abData
End Sub
```

From this method i'm getting an error from browser like

WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6701/' failed: Invalid frame header